# XMPP Google Talk X-OAUTH2 login requires username

Tags: xmpp, oauth-2.0, google-talk

I'm implementing an XMPP client for Google Talk that is using the relatively new X-OAUTH2 mechanism. I had the idea that I shouldn't need to store either username or password for the authentication to the service. However, [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/talk/jep_extensions/oauth) for the X-OAUTH2 authentication states this is the initial `<auth>` request to make:

```
<auth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"
    mechanism="X-OAUTH2"
    auth:service="oauth2"
    xmlns:auth="http://www.google.com/talk/protocol/auth">
  base64("\0" + user_name + "\0" + oauth_token)
</auth>
```

Note that it requires the "user_name" to be sent along with the token. Is there something I'm missing here? Or do I really have to have my application prompt for the username? (Note that the user would already have logged in via OAuth2 to receive the access token)

I don't know of any other service that uses OAuth that requires the client to provide a username. For instance, this same app can connect to Facebook Chat via XMPP and OAuth2 without needing the username to be provided in XMPP.

Comment: I am using strophe.js for implementing XMPP for Google Talk. 
I am already using Google OAuth for login into my application.
Can you please tell me, how to use the X-OAUTH2 mechanism to make the <auth> request using strophe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to prompt for username in your application. Just specify "SCOPE" parameter as "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email".
Refer [this](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#scopeparameter). This will give you users email-ID in response along with token.

This [Link](http://www.gethugames.in/blog/2012/04/authentication-and-authorization-for-google-apis-in-javascript-popup-window-tutorial.html) has detailed explanation about Google Accounts Authentication and Authorization. Username and email-id is returned in getUserInfo() function which you can use in your application.

Comment: That worked, unfortunately it shows the user the "see your email address" flag when authorizing the app, but at least I can get the email address. Note that it required an extra HTTP request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=<token>... But I think I can live with that. Thanks!